# My Jests tests are leaking memory, how can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, memory, jestjs

When I run my jest tests, the amount of memory used per test increases over time. The issue wasn't apparent on my local machine; instead, I found this out when running my tests on CircleCI. I got the following error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/pages/login.test.tsx
 
  ● Test suite failed to run
 
    jest: failed to cache transform results in: /tmp/jest_2ne/jest-transform-cache-7bdebd1a0c578519274d14a78b89f87c-f8238a99880aac6151736010e575fab1/0b/symbols_0bf4cffb45cb261625f2f3fca21a4789.map
 
    Failure message: ENOMEM: not enough memory, write
 
      at writeFileSync (node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:215:10)
      at writeCacheFile (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:809:33)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:554:7)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:586:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:624:25)
```

How can I fix my jest configuration to prevent this?

Comment: Could you solve it? if not, could you upload your package.json?

Answer (score 33):

First of all, make sure that you have leaky tests by running jest with the option:
`jest --logHeapUsage`

Run your tests and check that the memory consumption is increasing over time, like this (file names changed):

```
PASS  __tests__/pages/file.test.tsx (181 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/file2.test.tsx (193 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/Header/file3.test.tsx (201 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/Header/file4.test.tsx (192 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/Header/file5.test.tsx (218 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/file6.test.tsx (201 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file6.test.tsx (203 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file7.test.tsx (213 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file8.test.tsx (234 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file9.test.tsx (222 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file10.test.tsx (240 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file11.test.tsx (231 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/utils/file12.test.tsx (239 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file13.test.tsx (251 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file14.test.tsx (239 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file15.test.tsx (249 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file16.test.tsx (143 MB heap size)
```

To fix this, change your `npm run test` or `yarn test` command in your `package.json` to:
`node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage`

Run the command. Here's my output:

```
 PASS  __tests__/components/file.test.tsx (143 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/onboarding/file1.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file2.test.tsx (146 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file3.test.tsx (146 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file4.test.tsx (153 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/Header /file5.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/file6.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/file7.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file8.test.tsx (147 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file9.test.tsx (148 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/file10.test.tsx (148 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/Header /file11.test.tsx (148 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/functions/file12.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file13.test.tsx (148 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file14.test.tsx (150 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file15.test.tsx (150 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/Header /file16.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file17.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/utils/file18.test.tsx (150 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/components/file19.test.tsx (149 MB heap size)
 PASS  __tests__/pages/file20.test.tsx (150 MB heap size)
```

As you can see, the memory consumption is much more consistent.

You can read more about this issue and the solution in [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7874), which describes a leaky garbage collector issue with jest.

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same issue when running integration tests, where initially the heap size was about 160MB and it climbed up to ~1600MB locally and went OOM in CI. This issue also caused random tests to start failing with `Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.`
The main discussion for this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11956) where at the top you can find a [quick fix for it](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#workeridlememorylimit-numberstring). For the fix you'd have to set the `workerIdleMemoryLimit` flag in your config:

```js
// jest.config.js

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
    workerIdleMemoryLimit: '512MB',
};

module.exports = config;
```

Environment:

- node: 16.15.0
- jest: 29.5.0
- ts-jest: 29.0.5

After changes in config, the heap size stayed below the limit and fixed the timeout fails.
As an added bonus the tests ran faster locally ~20s and in CI ~4m (using `--maxWorkers 4` cli option)

Comment: after spending 3 days, only this solution works :)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. thanks! Do you know how it works?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `jest -w 1` to avoid these memory issues.

More information on [Jest CLI documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli)

> --maxWorkers=|# Alias: -w. Specifies the maximum number of workers the worker-pool will spawn for running tests. In single run
> mode, this defaults to the number of the cores available on your
> machine minus one for the main thread. In watch mode, this defaults to
> half of the available cores on your machine to ensure Jest is
> unobtrusive and does not grind your machine to a halt. It may be
> useful to adjust this in resource-limited environments like CIs but
> the defaults should be adequate for most use-cases.

Answer (score 7):

My environment is:

- Node 18.12.1
- Jest 29.3.1
- ts-jest 29.0.3

My npm script to run the test is `jest --coverage`. When I run the test I get this error

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Using `v8` as a coverage provider works for me.

```
// Example jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    coverageProvider: 'v8', // Default is 'babel'
    transform: {
        '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'ts-jest'
    }
};
```

Ref. https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coverageprovider-string

Comment: Heads up: leaking memory and running out of memory are two different things. Your environment is running out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it happened when I used a complex object:

```
expect(spyFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(COMPLEX_OBJECT_WITH_DIFFICULT_STRUCTURE);
```

So you can get *heap out of memory error* when you use jest **toEqual** utility (it compares recursively all properties of object).

As a solution try to replace "complexObject" with "simplifiedObject":

- expect.objectContaining({ ...someOfComplexObjectProps })
- expect.any(Object)

Answer (score 2):

Switching to node version 16.10 fixed the issue for me. Apparently, the memory leak with jest only happens with node version > 16.
I simply used [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to first install node 16.10 by running `nvm install 16.10`. After doing this, running my jest tests used 555MB as opposed to 1.5GB of memory.

Comment: downgrading shouldnt be an option

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted solution but it does shine light on a problem. I experienced the same issue going from node14 -> node16 -> node18 where memory appeared to be collected less frequently, and I could observe large jumps where memory would be deleted by the GB (going from 3000MB -> 1600MB for example).

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few different solutions that **didn't** work for me:

- increasing `--max-old-space-size`
- using the node flag: `node --no-compilation-cache`
- use  `--runInBand`
- use `--expose-gc`
- limiting the number of workers

What **did** work for me:

[Limiting the idle memory per worker](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#workeridlememorylimit-numberstring)

I'm also limiting the number of workers so maybe it was a combination of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else:

What didn't work for me:

- `--max-old-space-size`
- `--no-compilation-cache`
- `--runInBand`
- `--expose-gc`
- `--maxWorkers`
- `--workerIdleMemoryLimit`

What did work in the end:

- `--clearMocks`

(Same result to add `jest.clearAllMocks()` to the `beforeEach` on each suite)

Went round the houses on this one - `workerIdleMemoryLimit` only seemed to work between suites rather than between each test ([as per the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/configuration#workeridlememorylimit-numberstring)) so also got it working by setting this and splitting up my larger suites, but was not happy with that as a final fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things mention as above and others solutions but did not work,please do below config it will work fine if still not work upgrade node will help.

this will help in two things speeding test run and resolve heap memory

1. add `--workerIdleMemoryLimit=350` in jest command like below

   jest --env=jsdom --verbose a --coverage --max-old-space-size=16384 --silent --logHeapUsage --workerIdleMemoryLimit=350

change value of workerIdleMemoryLimit according you system configuration

2. add `isolatedModules: true` in jest config transform property like below

   transform: {
   '^.+\.ts?$': ['ts-jest', {
   isolatedModules: true
   }]
   }